# Building the setup.py file in cx_Freeze gets me this error : No such file or directory: 'linux-vdso.so.1'

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I made a setup.py file for my main.py file which uses the packages : `numba, pyglet and numpy` which looks like this:

```
cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {
"packages": ["pyglet", "llvmlite", "numpy", "numba"], 
"excludes": ["tkinter", "pygame"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name="guifoo",
    version="0.1",
    description="My GUI application!",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("main.py", base=base)],
)
```

However I keep get this error when I try to run `python setup.py.build` I keep getting this error:

```
creating directory /home/onuelito/Documents/Python Projects/paint/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.10/lib
copying /home/onuelito/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cx_Freeze/bases/lib/libcrypt-796a3fb8.so.2 -> /home/onuelito/Documents/Python Projects/paint/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.10/lib/libcrypt-796a3fb8.so.2
copying linux-vdso.so.1 -> /home/onuelito/Documents/Python Projects/paint/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.10/lib/linux-vdso.so.1
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'linux-vdso.so.1'
```

My OS is Manjaro XFCE btw.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Manjaro KDE.